# DevTools failed to load the source map for swiper-bundle.min.js.map in the Elementor

Tags: wordpress, slider, swiper.js, elementor

For my WordPress website, I'm using the Elementor plugin, and one of my sliders isn't working properly. I get the following error message when I open Chrome DevTools:

"DevTools was unable to load the source map: The following content could not be loaded for /wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/swiper/v8/swiper-bundle.min.js.map: net::ERR HTTP RESPONSE CODE FAILURE HTTP error: status code 404"

This error appears to be related to the swiper-bundle.min.js file used by Elementor's slider. I tried disabling other plugins and using the default WordPress theme, but the error remains.

Can someone explain what this error means and how I can fix it so that my slider works? I'm not familiar with source maps and would appreciate any help or advice. Thank you very much.